# Azure Resource Group adding access Active Directory Application not showing up

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I am following the directions here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/

And I am stuck in the **Assign application to role** section in step 6 when I am trying to add my application as a user - it is simply not showing up when I search for it by name - any idea what I am missing?  Thank you.

Comment: Check to see if you are in the right subscription, and the correct AD directory.

Comment: Are you following the PowerShell, Azure CLI or portal instructions?